# How to decrease Elm compile time on Circle CI or Travis CI?

Tags: cpu, travis-ci, elm, circleci

elm compilation is very slow on ci (circle/travis). I personally suffer from >30m build times on circle for a rather small elm project. https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1473 suggests "CPU count detection is the problem" and recommends using `libsysconfcpus` to return 1 CPU in lieu of the actual detected amount. Is there another way to mitigate this long compilation time?

Comment: using `libsysconfcpus` seems a less than desirable solution, though I am attempting it

Comment: I won't accept my answer as it's only a confirmation of the fix recommended in https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1473. I'm looking for a less hacky way of decreasing elm build time in ci.

Comment: Did you try caching `elm-stuff/build-artifacts` (which I think is also mentioned in issue 1473)? That worked for me (down from 15 minutes to around 4 minutes), but I think things have to run in the dependencies phase to be cached.

Answer (score 8):

From https://elmlang.slack.com/archives/general/p1484149451013255

@rtfeldman:

> there's a known speed problem with both Circle and Travis because they
>   misreport their number of CPUs, but there's a workaround: add the
>   equivalent of these to your Circle config:
>
> - https://github.com/elm-community/elm-test/blob/master/.travis.yml#L6
> - https://github.com/elm-community/elm-test/blob/master/.travis.yml#L22-L30
> - https://github.com/elm-community/elm-test/blob/master/.travis.yml#L39-L41
>     (edited)
>
> they basically swap out `elm-make` for a script that runs `elm-make`
>   with `sysconfcpus -n 2` so that `elm-make` becomes aware of the
>   *actual*  number of CPUs available
>
> I talked with the Circle folks a bit about this, and the tl;dr is that
>   they're not interested in fixing it, but it may fix itself in a future
>   release of some upstream stuff they're using

Comment: this is the exact solution that I linked to that I wanted to stay away from.

Comment: I will accept your answer if you can add a solution other than the `libsysconfcpus` one I linked to in the question and confirmed in my answer.

Comment: sorry, I haven't tested it

Answer (score 1):

Consider setting:

```
sudo: true
```

in your `.travis.yml`. It cut a Haskell build of mine from 18 minutes down to 3.

Answer (score 0):

for users looking for a quick and dirty fix: using `libsysconfcpus` to limit the amount of cpus detected by sysconf indeed reduces elm-make time by an order of magnitude in circle ci.

Comment: still looking for another way to decrease build time in ci